# Cast to pointer from integer of different size error

Tags: c

I am error messages for these lines of code. Im not the best with programming, and can provide more information if need be.

```
int *linebreak(char *msg, int *breakn){ 
  
    breakn = (int*)count_breaks(msg); //"cast to pointer from integer of different size
    int *arr = (int*)malloc((int)breakn * sizeof(int)); //cast from pointer to integer of different size
```

Comment: `count_breaks` is not disclosed, but the message suggests that the function returns an integer and you are handling that incorrectly. Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and describe what you want to do.

Comment: Have you included `stdlib.h` ?

Comment: You might mean `*breakn = count_breaks(msg); int *arr = malloc(*breakn * sizeof(int));`?  (see also: [c - Do I cast the result of malloc? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc))

Comment: The error for `malloc()` means you did not `#include <stdlib.h>`.  The error for `count_breaks()` means you did not declare it before using it.  C99 and later requires functions to be declared (or defined) before being used; only C90 did not mandate that.  The error messages are from GCC — you should be using `-std=c18` (or 11 or 99; whatever your compiler supports).  GCC 5 upwards defaults to C11; GCC 4 and lower defaults to C90.  You should consider using `-Werror -Wall -Wextra` too, so that you don't try running code with compiler-diagnosable bugs in it.

Comment: That code looks like a REALLY bad idea...

Comment: [Edit] and show the prototype of `count_breaks`.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming that `count_breaks()` returns an int and not a pointer to int.
If that's the case, you could try to change your function to

```
int *linebreak(char *msg, int *breakn)
{
// count_breaks() should return an int
// and it should be assigned to the variable pointed by breakn
    *breakn = count_breaks(msg);

// In C the return value of malloc should not be cast, in C++ is needed though
// You were casting breakn to int, instead of dereferencing it
    int *arr = malloc(*breakn * sizeof(*arr));
```

Comment: The use of `*breakn` in the call to `malloc()` is important — well spotted!

Comment: Answers should explain, not just give code.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you, now that you let me think about it, I'd better comment on the 2 code changes

Comment: Consider sizing to the referenced object.`malloc(*breakn * sizeof(int));` --> `malloc(*breakn * sizeof(*arr));`